# Как правильно реализовать пошаговое выполнение сценария (функция за функцией)?

Tags: javascript

Реализую на сайте скринкаст работы с приложением на сss и js
Вопрос: Как правильно реализовать пошаговое выполнение сценария (функция за функцией)?
К примеру набор текста, потом нажатие кнопки, затем появление нового блока с этим тесктом и т.д. (под капотом это просто добавление/удаление классов, текста или объектов dom)
Возможно есть более правильные варианты кроме setTimeout?

Comment: Перефразируйте вопрос. Возможно почитайте асинхронные сценарии. Вполне возможно с помощью EventListener, но непонятно чего Вы хотите? Функции в js поднимаются в начало сценария и видны в любом месте кода (без вложенных функцй)

Comment: я написал пример того что мне надо - "К примеру набор текста, потом нажатие кнопки, затем появление нового блока с этим тесктом и т.д. (под капотом это просто добавление/удаление классов, текста или объектов dom"

Comment: А как вы узнаёте что первое действие закончилось и можно запускать второе? Это какое-то событие, или каждое действие строго фиксировано по времени и время известно заранее?

Comment: на данный момент устанавливая нужный мне setTimeout

Comment: в общем то проблема сейчас только в том, что используя setTimeout, при переключении вкладок, функции могут не выполнится полностью. И хотелось узнать может есть более изящное решение учитывающее эти проблемы

Comment: @IceDvl если только как-то отслеживать выполнение анимации через события.

Answer (score 0):

Да, всё верно, используя **setTimeout**.

Но если его тупо использовать, то код будет выглядеть некрасиво, поэтому надо сделать свою функцию очереди анимации.

Выглядеть это может так.

```
DoAction(action1,3000).DoAction(action2,1000).DoAction(action3,4000);
```

Второй вариант через массив.

```
var arr = [ { action: action1, pause: 1000},
            { action: action2, pause: 2000},
            { action: action3, pause: 4000} ];
```

Другим решением без использования привязки к фиксированному времени может быть **отслеживание событий анимации**.

Читаем тут - [How to Capture CSS3 Animation Events in JavaScript](https://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/).

Comment: ну так и работает, но вот проблема, при переключении вкладок не все функции могут сработать, так как setTimeout работает в фоне, но как-то странно, етсть мысли на эту тему?

Comment: @IceDvl отлавливать переключение вкладок и делать паузу